# QT/C++ on MAC - How do I hide my dock icon?

Tags: qt, macos

I'd like my dock icon to be hidden and the app to be represented as a menu bearing icon on the menu bar (right hand side).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will hide the icon:

http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/disable-the-dock-icon-for-any-application.html

Summarizing the URL, in the dict xml element inside `Info.plist` in the app, add the lines:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

You need to use the appropriate OS APIs to add the menu.

Comment: How is this answer related to QT and C++?

Comment: @semanswer The best solution to hiding the app in the dock isn't QT or C++ code. It's an OS-level answer.

Comment: This certainly works, but I'm still personally on the hunt for guidance on how to do this form QT so that I don't have to figure it out for every operating system.

Comment: It hides icon from dock, but minimising the window creates an element in the docs all the same...

Answer (score 3):

The alternative answer is by using [`TransformProcessType()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1462420-transformprocesstype?language=objc) to show/hide dock icon dynamically in code.

```cpp
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void toggleDockIcon(bool show) {
  ProcessSerialNumber psn = {0, kCurrentProcess};
  if (show) {
    TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);
  } else {
    TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToUIElementApplication);
  }
}
```