# Java Hide Dock Icon in Mac osx

Tags: java, macos, dock, trayicon

I want to make a system tray without icon of Mac osx dock, just only tray icon using java code.

I developed the tray function but I cannot hide the dock icon.

Is it possible? What can i do for that? help me.

Comment: You should explain a bit more because this is not really clear. But, what have your tried for the moment ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT/C++ on MAC - How do I hide my dock icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718668/qt-c-on-mac-how-do-i-hide-my-dock-icon)