# Instantiating a Java AWT object causes empty application to open on macOS

Tags: java, awt

When I instantiate an object from `java.awt`, the program causes a new macOS application named "Java", with no windows, to open.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is a minimal example:

```java
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    }

}
```

After compiling and running it in the most canonical way (`javac Main.java; java Main`), the following icon appears in the Dock: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX7y1.png)

I've traced the code, and the offending method is `Toolkit.loadLibraries()` (JDK `1.8.0_172-b11`).

Comment: Short answer, you can't.  This is simply how MacOS works. The "long" answer would require you to generate a .app bundle :/

Comment: @MadProgrammer I see, thanks. Out of curiosity, do you have a reference for reading about .app bundles? (googling ".app bundle" without googling "app bundle" is surprisingly hard)

Comment: Try something more like [java apple app bundle](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+apple+app+bundle&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and [java apple app bundle icon](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&ei=nGcVXdHxENC8-gSChKvIDQ&q=java+apple+app+bundle+icon&oq=java+apple+app+bundle+icon&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160l2.30839.31317..31521...0.0..0.283.1027.2-4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i22i29i30.GsIFunFRXEk) and no, it's not easy :/

Comment: You may also want to look at things like "macOS java hide dock icon", for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718668/qt-c-on-mac-how-do-i-hide-my-dock-icon) or [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071208235352641) (but I'm not sure if it still works)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ahh yes that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! You can indeed configure awt. I'll make an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution based on [@MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783862/instantiating-a-java-awt-object-causes-empty-application-to-open-on-macos?noredirect=1#comment100154505_56783862).

The answer is to set AWT to headless mode.

When executing the program:

```
$ java -Djava.awt.headless=true Main
```

Or programatically:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```