# Hide application icon from taskbar using pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am creating desktop application using python pyqt5. i want hide my application icon from taskbar i am using following code to hide application.

```
def __init__(self):
   super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
   self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool)
```

but after this i am facing application not responding issue.any one have idea how can we hide application icon?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "not responding"? And what OS is this intended for?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, if you write your app in a `.pyw` file, no window will open, so you won't get any app icon in taskbar either.

In MacOS you have to use a plist: [QT/C++ on MAC - How do I hide my dock icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718668/qt-c-on-mac-how-do-i-hide-my-dock-icon)